# use of VisualSVN as a remote backup

Tags: backup, visualsvn

I have a windows server, I can install VisualSVN on this machine.

What I would like to do is, use use some kind of batch script (MS DOS .BAT) to remotely backup files to this server over https (I can schedule this script to run nightly).

**< ignore >** This will always be a one way copy, i.e. what ever is in the respository should ALWAYS be over-written with what ever is in the client machine **< / ignore >**

Assume I have a local folder on the client machine as such:

c:\Data

**Question:**

- (a) On the client machine(s) would I need to install any kind of SVN client software?
- (b) Can anyone help with the batch script to achieve this?

**Edit:**

I assume SVN will automatically only transfer files that have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you're confusing two things:

1. A copy operation, which simply is a file system operation where no VCS whatsoever is involved. Otherwise your notion of 'overwrite' doesn't make any sense, because VCS systems are there to avoid exactly that.
2. A scheduled check-in operation, which can only be initiated from a client machine. Therefore, it of course has to have a SVN client installed.

Thomas

Comment: having re-read again your correct its confusing so please ignore the copy operation item.

Comment: I see. So what you have in mind is an automatic, scheduled check-in. This must be done by a client, because a version control server never pulls from clients, it only receives push operations. So yes, you need to have SVN clients installed. I'm sure you'll find respective scripts if your searching the SVN homepage http://subversion.apache.org.